# Could not Load NIB for the Third Time?

Tags: iphone, ios, bundle, xib

IN my application i am using this code to Call my First Class Xib.Here is my Code.

```
     -(IBAction)retryagain
     {      
      firstview *sec=[[firstview alloc] initWithNibName:@"firstview" bundle:nil];
      sec.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
      [self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES];
      [sec release];
      }
```

This Code works fine for 6 or 7 minutes after running my application ,but when i call this code after 6 or 7 minute. then my application Crash its give me the following in Console.
        [image]

Any One can guide me how To solve this problem.any help will be appriated.Thanx in Advance.

Comment: there is no error in ur code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle….' with name 'firstview'*

**Answer :**

> It looks like you're trying to instantiate a nib called 'firstview'
>   and it isn't present. Is the nib included as a project member? In
>   project -> Build Phases
>
> Make sure the .xib is added to Copy Bundle Resources

Comment: Thanx for every one,but when i closely check my application.i think due to memory leaks this fuction not works.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is working fine for me . Please check the nib name you entered here with the actual name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the new xcode version I would suggest to exit xcode and restart your mac, then clean the project and try again. I had some weird nib errors caused by something faulty in xcode and a restart somehow fixed them.

Another suggestion would be to delete the nib file and remake it. I had a similar problem with a nib once and recreating the file fixed everything.

I doubt it something wrong with your code, you would have encountered this error every time you tried to load the nib, not on the third time, as I understand from your question